# Is there a way for JAXB to marshall the new xml according to the order from the xml file read in?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I wonder if there is a way for JAXB to marshall the new xml according to the order from the xml file it read in?

For example, the new file written out, the first line below is like

```
<f saved="0" id="M" type="boolean" > as you can see the order is changed
```

Original

```
<f id="M" type="boolean" saved="0">
  <description>Select</description>
  <default>1</default>
</f>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ensure the order the order in which JAXB marshals out XML attributes.

JAXB's `Binder` is probably closest to what you are looking for.  With a `Binder` a DOM is unmarshalled changes are made to an object, and then on a marshal the data is applied to the original DOM.  Since it deals with a DOM it's probably a heavier weight solution than what you need.  Also since in XML attribute order is not significant it wouldn't be guaranteed to give you what you are looking for.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html